# List Django database table names from external script

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am trying to access sqlite3 database that I have in my Django project from within external script that is not part of the project.

However, the following will return an empty list:

```
con = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';")
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

Even though I have already saved some models to the database.
To check the table names, I use the following in Django shell:

```
>>> tables = connection.introspection.table_names()
>>> seen_models = connection.introspection.installed_models(tables)
>>> seen_models
{<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.Permission'>, <class 'django.contrib.sessions.models.Session'>, <class 'django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType'>, <class 'explorer_api.models.Athlete'>, <class 'django.contrib.admin.models.LogEntry'>, <class 'django.contrib.auth.models.Group'>, <class 'explorer_api.models.Activity'>, <class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'>}
>>> tables
['auth_group', 'auth_group_permissions', 'auth_permission', 'auth_user', 'auth_user_groups', 'auth_user_user_permissions', 'django_admin_log', 'django_content_type', 'django_migrations', 'django_session', 'explorer_api_activity', 'explorer_api_athlete']
```

I have not specified the table names explicitly in model's Meta, so I guess the table names are `appname_modelname` (`explorer_api_activity` and `explorer_api_athlete`).

But why the empty list?

Comment: have you used the correct name of the database?

Comment: You're right, the above scripts work only when it is in the same folder as the database. What if I want it to be elsewhere? In such case I am currently referencing the database location like this:`'/media/barciewicz/DATA/python_projects/strava/explorer_api/db.sqlite3'`, but this is when empty list is returned.

Comment: Yes its possible. Please see my answer on this. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*From comments on on the question:*
Yes its possible to run this script as long as you have a valid path to the file. I have rewritten your script with minor changes like this:

```
import sqlite3
import os.path

try:
    file_name = raw_input("Enter File Path? ")
except:
    file_name = input("Enter File Path? ")
if os.path.isfile(file_name):
    con = sqlite3.connect(file_name)
    cursor = con.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';")
    print(cursor.fetchall())
else:
    print("File does not exist")
```

Usage:

```
> python sqlite_tables.py
  (prompt)> Enter File Path? random/file/path
  (prompt)> File does not exist

> python sqlite_tables.py
  (prompt)> Enter File Path? /valid/path/to/database.db
  (prompt)> [(u'django_migrations',), (u'sqlite_sequence',)...]

> python sqlite_tables.py
  (prompt)> Enter File Path? ../database.db  # relative path
  (prompt)> [(u'django_migrations',), (u'sqlite_sequence',)...]
```